# PowerPoint VBA Changing font color of selected item in chart

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I know this sounds simple, but I haven't found any solution in the web nor this site.

So, I have a macro in Excel that changes the font color of any selected item -- range, chart, textbox, etc. -- and the code is quite simple:

```
Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0,0,0)
```

But in PowerPoint there is not such thing as the "Selection" wildcard in Excel. In PowerPoint this work well for textboxes --

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0,0,0)
```

But it does not work for charts and tables. So, for charts I use this code --

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB RGB(0,0,0)
```

The problem is that it changes all the text in the chart -- title, labels, axis, etc. And I only need to change the font color of the selected item. for example, only the title or only the labels, depending on what the user decides to select.

I don't know how to discriminate what item is selected in the chart, in order to apply the change only to it. For example --

```
.ChartTitle.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB, etc.
```

Is there a way to identify what item is selected? Or to apply the changes only to it? Thank you.

Comment: The main use is having color options for a corporative brand. As there are several variations, the theme colors are no enough. Thus, in Excel I have buttons for each color and the user decides what he/she wants to color. It works fine. But in PowerPoint I cannot find a way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. Instead of `.ChartArea` you can access other chart items, such as `.ChartTitle`.

This example loops through all the shapes on a slide, including some extra checks to prevent errors.  If the shape has a chart, the chart has a title and title has text, specify the color for the chart's title font.

```
Sub FontColor_ChartTitle()

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

        'Loop through all shapes on the slide
        For i = 1 To .Shapes.Count

            With .Shapes(i)

                'If the shape is a chart
                If .HasChart Then

                    'If the chart has a title
                    If .Chart.HasTitle Then

                        With .Chart.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2

                            'If the title contains text
                            If .HasText Then

                                With .TextRange.Font

                                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(95, 37, 97)

                                End With

                            End If

                        End With

                    End If

                End If

            End With

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, is there a way to apply the code to the selected item? Sometimes could be the title, and others a label. I don't want to apply the font color always to the same item, but only the one that the user has selected.

Comment: @manu197a Can you provide an example of your color buttons? In your Excel example, does the user select a part of the table and then click one of the buttons? Does that button launch a color picker or is it a static color?

Comment: Also, can you tell me if dual monitors are used and if this will be a primary template file from which users will copy the file to customize for their use?

Comment: So, the buttons are static colors -- I have for example a Green and a Blue ones. Each is a button in my ribbon. When the user presses the button, any selected text is colored to the specific RGB defined in the code. In Excel this is as simple as a one line:
Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0,0,0)
The ribbon is not a template for user to change the color, but instead a help for them to only use these colors (as the company is quite intolerant when we use any other color)

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer to your question is, unfortunately, no. The PPT object model has no way of returning the selected item in a chart.

John Korchok's suggestion should allow you to offer the desired colors to your users to choose, though.

Answer (score 2):

Since the basic issue is providing the client with more colors while avoiding having them input RGB values, I think you might want to evaluate the simplest most flexible way to do that. 
For color options beyond the theme colors, adding Custom Colors to the file is a better way to go. I would drop all the VBA selection-based formatting. This article emphasizes PowerPoint, but custom colors can be used in Word and Excel as well: [Custom Colors added to color picker](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/06/xml-hacking-custom-colors/)

Comment: John, thank you for the suggestion. I'll try this option as it seems to be the most convenient one. But users in my company know NOTHING about Office, I doubt they will be able to downoad the theme file, open PP, selec it and use the colors -- that's why we need this ribbon, for them to just press a button and get the right color. Thus, I'll try to come up with a code to create my own theme file from scratch, save it to disc, select it and tell the users that they now can use the theme colors. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: What's the source for users for your VBA code? If it's a macro-enabled presentation or template, you would add the custom colors to that. The problem of distribution is the same for VBA and custom colors. In addition, many companies are able to use Group Policies under Windows to roll out the files to users that they need. Your I.T. department will know more.